# Eslint is working from terminal, but not showing error in the editor UI (VSCode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

I've installed the ESlint by following these steps:  https://travishorn.com/setting-up-eslint-on-vs-code-with-airbnb-javascript-style-guide-6eb78a535ba6

Now, my ESlint is working from the terminal, but errors/warnings are not displaying in the code window, here is my project structure and how it is looks like:

[image: eslint terminal]

**and my `eslintrc` configs:**

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
  },
  rules: {
  },
};
```

Why it couldn't show errors in the editor?

Comment: You have the eslint extension installed too, right? This one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: Your instructions tell you to create the eslintrc file yourself, did you try just having eslint do it do you automatically by using `npx eslint --init`? I would try that since you don't have custom rules, just to ensure that your config file is correct and rule that out as a possible cause.

Comment: I have ESLint extension installed, and I've also created `.eslintrc` with the `eslint --init`

Comment: Under settings > eslint, make sure Eslint:Enabled is checked.

Comment: I am having the same issue, everything works well with prettier and the webpack loader (errors and warning displayed at build in terminal) but no linting on the code itself

Comment: Do you get any messages in the Output tab? The Output tab is in the bottom panel, you can select ESLint in the dropdown menu on the top right corner of the same panel. Most likely the ESLint in VSCode is having problems to either finding the config file or with the content of the config file.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this recently, and fixed it by changing my `.eslintrc.js` file to just `.eslintrc` (JSON object only, no comments, everything quoted right, no extension). After restarting VSCode it picked up the file properly and gave me linter errors in VSCode.

Comment: This worked! Idk why it worked... but I'm glad it did

Comment: This didn't work for me :(

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't need to change any filename, just needed to close the VSCode window, then reopen the window for my project (`code .`), and it loaded all the eslint errors, as desired. Thanks for the "restart" tip!

Comment: Eslint just stopped working in my project one day. I did the opposite where I had a `.eslintrc` and changed it to `.eslintrc.js`. That made it showing lint warnings again. I changed the filename back to `.eslintrc` again and it kept working so, it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

for me it's work !

setting.json add this

```
"eslint.validate": [
    "vue",
    "html",
    "javascript",
    "typescript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescriptreact"
]
```

https://linuxpip.org/eslint-not-working-in-vscode/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **VSCode** and **Windows**, **ESLint** is configured **correctly**, the **extension is enabled** and the **errors do not appear in the files**, but the **lint command lists the errors in the terminal**, it may be that the **VSCode version is out of date**.

If for some reason you have set **[VSCode to always open as administrator, automatic updates will be disabled](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows)**.

Consequently, it may be that the VSCode version is obsolete with respect to the ESLint extension.

You can analyze possible ESLint errors in the terminal as follows:

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + U` (will open the Output terminal);
2. Select `ESLint`, in the select on the right;
3. If a message similar to the one below appears:

> "The language client requires VS Code version ^1.82.0 but received version 1.79.1".

**Updating the VSCode version** and **reopening it** should resolve the issue.

Comment: For people who always open VScode from terminal via `.code` command, vscode will always be opened with the privilege you have on the terminal. For me, I always open terminal with admin privilege, thus opening vscode as admin, and vscode never checked for update. After updating vscode, all eslint errors are showing up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I followed all the advice and still had issues. I am using Typescript + YARN 2 (w\ PnP).

The error I was receiving was `Failed to load the ESLint library for the document [filename].ts`

What fixed it for me was that I needed to create some editor SDKs and settings with the command:

`yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`.

My .vscode/settings.json for eslint looks like:

```json
  "eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.packageManager": "yarn",
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.validate": [
    "html",
    "javascript",
    "typescript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],
  "eslint.nodePath": ".yarn/sdks"
```

The command above added `"eslint.nodePath": ".yarn/sdks"`

I found this [here](https://next.yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks) (I followed [this](https://next.yarnpkg.com/advanced/pnpify#vscode-support) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/601) to get there).

Comment: Thank you for this! This worked for me when using .eslintrc.js. However, the new "flat config" system (eslint.config.js) is still problematic with the VS Code ESLint extension even though they have a flag to enable it. I'll fall back to using the old config for a little while longer. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint#release-notes